# Get a list of file names from HDFS using python

Tags: python, hadoop

Hadoop noob here.

I've searched for some tutorials on getting started with hadoop and python without much success. I do not need to do any work with mappers and reducers yet, but it's more of an access issue.

As a part of Hadoop cluster,
there are a bunch of .dat files on the HDFS.

In order to access those files on my client (local computer) using Python,

> what do I need to have on my computer?
>
> How do I query for filenames on HDFS ?

Any links would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have login access to a node in the cluster. Let the cluster administrator pick the node and setup the account and inform you how to access the node securely. If you are the administrator, let me know if the cluster is local or remote and if remote then is it hosted on your computer, inside a corporation or on a 3rd party cloud and if so whose and then I can provide more relevant information.

To query file names in HDFS, login to a cluster node and run `hadoop fs -ls [path]`. *Path* is optional and if not provided, the files in your home directory are listed.  If `-R` is provided as an option, then it lists all the files in path recursively. There are additional options for this command. For more information about this and other Hadoop file system shell commands see http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html.

An easy way to query HDFS file names in Python is to use `esutil.hdfs.ls(hdfs_url='', recurse=False, full=False)`, which executes `hadoop fs -ls hdfs_url` in a subprocess, plus it has functions for a number of other Hadoop file system shell commands (see the source at http://code.google.com/p/esutil/source/browse/trunk/esutil/hdfs.py). *esutil* can be installed with `pip install esutil`. It is on PyPI at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esutil, documentation for it is at http://code.google.com/p/esutil/ and its GitHub site is https://github.com/esheldon/esutil.

Comment: Don't have login access but could mount it onto a local drive. From there, I can see the files successfully, now I could read them using subprocess even without using hadoop commands I'm assuming.

Comment: What kind of mount?  For example a fuse mount does not preserve HDFS semantics and provides access using standard unix/linux utilities which seems dangerous to me unless its read only.

Comment: Precisely. Will be making a local copy. The purpose i need it for is not to modify anything, just to read some things. But if and when I need to proceed with HDFS semantics, I will be referring to this post again.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I've been able to tell there is no out-of-the-box solution for this, and most answers I've found have resorted to using calls to the `hdfs` command.  I'm running on Linux, and have the same challenge.  I've found the `sh` package to be useful.  This handles running o/s commands for you and managing stdin/out/err.

See here for more info on it: https://github.com/amoffat/sh

Not the neatest solution, but it's one line (ish) and uses standard packages.

Here's my cut-down code to grab an HDFS directory listing.  It will list files and folders alike, so you might need to modify if you need to differentiate between them.

```
import sh
hdfsdir = '/somedirectory'
filelist = [ line.rsplit(None,1)[-1] for line in sh.hdfs('dfs','-ls',hdfsdir).split('\n') if len(line.rsplit(None,1))][1:]
```

My output - In this case these are all directories:

```
[u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-01',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-02',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-03',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-04',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-05',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-06',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-07',
 u'/somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-08']
```

Let's break it down:

To run the `hdfs dfs -ls /somedirectory` command we can use the `sh` package like this:

```
import sh
sh.hdfs('dfs','-ls',hdfsdir)
```

`sh` allows you to call o/s commands seamlessly as if they were functions on the module.  You pass command parameters as function parameters.  Really neat.

For me this returns something like:

```
Found 366 items
drwxrwx---+  - impala hive          0 2016-05-10 13:52 /somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-01
drwxrwx---+  - impala hive          0 2016-05-10 13:52 /somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-02
drwxrwx---+  - impala hive          0 2016-05-10 13:52 /somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-03
drwxrwx---+  - impala hive          0 2016-05-10 13:52 /somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-04
drwxrwx---+  - impala hive          0 2016-05-10 13:52 /somedirectory/transaction_basket_fct/date_id=2015-01-05
```

Split that into lines based on new line characters using `.split('\n')`

Obtain the last 'word' in the string using `line.rsplit(None,1)[-1]`.

To prevent issues with empty elements in the list use `if len(line.rsplit(None,1))`

Finally remove the first element in the list (the `Found 366 items`) using `[1:]`

Comment: This was a great help. I made a more transparent function that uses regex to do the string parsing in a little more transparent way (edit: moved this to an answer b/c code formatting won't work in comments)

Comment: The link does not exist. I updated it.

Answer (score 6):

for the "query for filenames on HDFS" using just raw subprocess library for python 3:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hdfs_path = '/path/to/the/designated/folder'
process = Popen(f'hdfs dfs -ls -h {hdfs_path}', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
list_of_file_names = [fn.split(' ')[-1].split('/')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().split('\n')[1:]][:-1]
list_of_file_names_with_full_address = [fn.split(' ')[-1] for fn in std_out.decode().split('\n')[1:]][:-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

> what do I need to have on my computer?

You need Hadoop installed and running and ofcourse, Python.

> How do I query for filenames on HDFS ?

You can try something like this here. I haven't tested the code so don't just rely on it.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen('hdfs dfs -cat filename.dat',shell=True,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()

check for returncode, std_err
if:
    everything is OK, do whatever with stdout
else:
    do something in else condition
```

You can also look at [Pydoop](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/tutorial/index.html) which is a Python API for Hadoop.

Although my example include `shell=true`, you can try running without it as it is a security risk. [Why you shouldn't use `shell=True`?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

As JGC stated, the most straightforward thing you could do is start by logging onto (via `ssh`) one of the nodes (a server that is participating in a Hadoop cluster) and verifying that you have the correct access controls and privileges to:

- List your home directory using the HDFS client i.e. `hdfs dfs -ls`
- List the directory of interest that lives in HDFS i.e. `hdfs dfs -ls <absolute or relative path to HDFS directory>`

Then, in Python, you should use subprocesses and the HDFS client to access the paths of interest, and use the `-C` flag to exclude unnecessary metadata (to avoid doing ugly post-processing later).

i.e. `Popen(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', '-C', dirname])`

Afterwards, split the output on new lines and then you will have your list of paths.

Here's an example along with logging and error handling (including for when the directory/file doesn't exist):

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

FAILED_TO_LIST_DIRECTORY_MSG = 'No such file or directory'

class HdfsException(Exception):
    pass

def hdfs_ls(dirname):
    """Returns list of HDFS directory entries."""
    logger.info('Listing HDFS directory ' + dirname)
    proc = Popen(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-ls', '-C', dirname], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    if out:
        logger.debug('stdout:\n' + out)
    if proc.returncode != 0:
        errmsg = 'Failed to list HDFS directory "' + dirname + '", return code ' + str(proc.returncode)
        logger.error(errmsg)
        logger.error(err)
        if not FAILED_TO_LIST_DIRECTORY_MSG in err:
            raise HdfsException(errmsg)
        return []
    elif err:
        logger.debug('stderr:\n' + err)
    return out.splitlines()

# dat_files will contain a proper Python list of the paths to the '.dat' files you mentioned above.
dat_files = hdfs_ls('/hdfs-dir-with-dat-files/')
```

Comment: Nice answer, but there are a few issues with byte string/str concats on Python 3.7 that were throwing errors: e.g. I had to change `logger.debug('stderr:\n' + err)` to `logger.debug(b'stderr:\n' + err)`. and the same for `FAILED_TO_LIST_DIRECTORY_MSG`.

Comment: Instead of the above, perhaps a better way to do this would be to pass `text=True`, or `encoding='utf-8'` to the `Popen` constructor, this will return results as text rather than bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by @JGC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599449/3945895) was a big help. I wanted a version that was a more transparent function instead of a harder to read one-liner; I also swapped the string parsing to use regex so that it is both more transparent and less brittle to changes in the hdfs syntax. This version looks like this, the same general approach as JGC:

```
import re
import sh


def get_hdfs_files(directory:str) -> List[str]:
    '''
    Params: 
    directory: an HDFS directory e.g. /my/hdfs/location
    '''
    output = sh.hdfs('dfs','-ls',directory).split('\n')
    files = []
    for line in output:
        match = re.search(f'({re.escape(directory)}.*$)', line)
        if match:
            files.append(match.group(0))

    return files
```

Comment: Much neater and, like you say, less brittle.