# Read Multiple Fixed width files and process it one by one

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, iteration

I have multiple fixed-width files in the HDFS directory and I want to read those files one by one. The code I have developed in PySpark is working for a single file.

Code:

```
    *df = sqlContext.read.text("/user/XXX/PBM_TAIL/FILE.PROD.TM234908_TAIL.txt")
     
*parexp1 = df.select(
        df.value.substr(1,2).alias('TLR_RECORD_TYPE'),
        df.value.substr(3,10).cast('integer').alias('TLR_TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT'),
        df.value.substr(13,12).alias('TLR_TOTAL_NET_AMOUNT_DUE')
       )*
       
    parexp1.registerTempTable("parexp2")
    parexp3 = sqlContext.sql("""
                                select TLR_RECORD_TYPE,
                                       TLR_TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT,
                                       TLR_TOTAL_NET_AMOUNT_DUE,
                                       reverse(split(reverse(input_file_name()),'/')[0]) as File_Name,
                                       udfFormatAmt(TLR_TOTAL_NET_AMOUNT_DUE) as TLR_TL_REC_CNT_CNV
                                       from parexp2 
                                             
                                            """)*
```

How do i convert above code to read the multiple files one by one and process it individually by dataframes?

Comment: get ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381942/get-a-list-of-file-names-from-hdfs-using-python to get the list of filenames from hdfs and then loop the list using your above logic. :) hope it helps

Comment: Are these multiple files have the same format / to be processed in the same way?

Comment: @Bala Yes, format of the file is same. I don't want to merge the files.

Comment: Can you not read the whole directory by `sqlContext.read.text("/user/XXX/PBM_TAIL/*)` ?

Comment: @Bala How do i process the files one by one after reading? Initially my requirement is to read one file, now things have changes. So, i am trying to leverage the existing code. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Ron:  You don't have to do anything.  Just read the whole directory and use your existing code as it is. Just try and let us know.

Comment: @Bala when i used the code as is, it is merging the files instead of looping one by one. Clearly i need to use FOR loop or something to iterate the file one by one, but i am not sure how to use in pyspark. Any pointer would be helpful.